# Can I specify host directory to mount from Dockerfile

Tags: docker

Docker run command has option to mount host directory into container

```
-v=[]: Create a bind mount with: [host-dir]:[container-dir]:[rw|ro]. 
       If "host-dir" is missing, then docker creates a new volume.
```

And Dockerfile has `VOLUME` instruction

```
VOLUME ["/data"] - The VOLUME instruction will add one or more new volumes 
                   to any container created from the image.
```

From what I see, there is no way to specify `host-dir` or rw/ro status when using Dockerfile.

Is there any other use of VOLUME in docker file other than wanting to share it with some other container?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Dockerfiles are meant to be portable and shared. The host-dir volume is something 100% host dependent and will break on any other machine, which is a little bit off the Docker idea.

Because of this, it is only possible to use portable instructions within a Dockerfile.  If you need a host-dir volume, you need to specify it at run-time.

A common usage of VOLUME from Dockerfile is to store configuration or website sources so that it can be updated later by another container.

Comment: And what about current directory with Dockerfile? It will always be portable,

Comment: Thanks for explaining why this is not offered. That makes sense now that I understand the design philosophy. Cannot say I like it, but I understand it now.

Comment: Great answer :). Also see the official Docker documentation at: [Notes about specifiying volumes](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#notes-about-specifying-volumes)

Comment: @creack Is not there any way? The **Dockerfile** is the single start point in my case for **airflow**. There is no necessity in portability as the image exists for the sole machine. This step is the most convenient for `pip install -e` command since there is no internet access after the container run & I need to run this command in each final container.