# How to convert Docker run flags into a Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have this docker run command:

```
docker run -d \
    --name node1 \
    --network host \
    -v $(pwd)/genesis.json:/opt/besu/genesis.json \
    -v $(pwd)/keys/validator1/key:/opt/besu/key \
    --env-file $(pwd)/common.env \
    --env-file $(pwd)/bootnodes.env \
    node1:latest
```

This works fine.

But I want to put the flags inside the Dockerfile, to just run `docker run -d node:latest`,

I've tried to use the `CMD[]` inside Dockerfile, but didn't work.

The container runs but after 1-3 seconds it dies.

Comment: In general your `Dockerfile` defines your image, but the flags you have here define your run-time (i.e. your container that is spawned from the image). Thus for this you need Docker Compose, which will read a `docker-compose.yml` config file.

Comment: [Can I specify host directory to mount from Dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18873474/can-i-specify-host-directory-to-mount-from-dockerfile) focuses on the `docker run -v` options (TL;DR: no, you can't name a host directory at build time), but you similarly can't for example disable Docker networking or force a container name from the Dockerfile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get access to host resources from inside a Dockerfile. It's very deliberate that those access rights have to be given at run-time. Otherwise it would be easy to distribute malicious Docker images that could access resources on the host machine without the knowledge of the user owning the host.

What you can do, is create a Docker Compose file called `docker-compose.yml` containing

```
version: '3'

services:
  myservice:
    container_name: node1
    image: node1:latest
    volumes:
      - ./genesis.json:/opt/besu/genesis.json
      - ./keys/validator1/key:/opt/besu/key
    env_file: 
      - ./common.env
      - ./bootnodes.env
    network_mode: host
```

That'll let you run the container using a simple

```
docker compose up -d
```

command, so you don't have to remember all the options.